# Add parameter "Build Selector for Copy Artifact" using Jenkins DSL

Tags: groovy, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-job-dsl

I'm converting a Jenkins job from a manual configuration to DSL which means I'm attempting to create a DSL script which creates the job(s) as it is today.

The job is currently parameterized and one of the parameters is of the type "Build Selector for Copy Artifact". I can see in the job XML that it is the copyartifact plugin and specifically I need to use the BuildSelectorParameter.

However the Jenkins DSL API has no guidance on using this plugin to set a parameter - it only has help for using it to create a build step, which is not what I need.

I also can't find anything to do with this under the parameter options in the API.

I want to include something in the DSL seed script which will create a parameter in the generated job matching the one in the image.

[parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zA5HA.png)

If I need to use the configure block then any tips on that would be welcome to because for a beginner, the documentation on this is pretty useless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found no other way to setup the build selector parameter but using the configure block. This is what I used to set it up:

```
freeStyleJob {
    ...
    configure { project ->
        def paramDefs = project / 'properties' / 'hudson.model.ParametersDefinitionProperty' / 'parameterDefinitions'
        paramDefs << 'hudson.plugins.copyartifact.BuildSelectorParameter'(plugin: "copyartifact@1.38.1") {
            name('BUILD_SELECTOR')
            description('The build number to deploy')
            defaultSelector(class: 'hudson.plugins.copyartifact.SpecificBuildSelector') {
                buildNumber()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In order to reach that, I manually created a job with the build selector parameter. And then looked for the job's XML configuration under jenkins to look at the relevant part, in my case:

```
<project>
    ...
    <properties>
        <hudson.model.ParametersDefinitionProperty>
            <parameterDefinitions>
                ...
                <hudson.plugins.copyartifact.BuildSelectorParameter plugin="copyartifact@1.38.1"
                    <name>BUILD_SELECTOR</name>
                    <description></description>
                    <defaultSelector class="hudson.plugins.copyartifact.SpecificBuildSelector">
                        <buildNumber></buildNumber>
                    </defaultSelector>
                </hudson.plugins.copyartifact.BuildSelectorParameter>
            </parameterDefinitions>
        </hudson.model.ParametersDefinitionProperty>
    </properties>
    ...
</project>
```

To replicate that using the `configure` clause you need to understand the following things:

- The first argument to the configure clause is the `job` node.
- Using the `/` operator will return a child of a node with the given node, if it doesn't exist gets created.
- Using the `<<` operator will append to the left-hand-side operand the node given as the right-hand-side operand.
- When creating a node, you can give it the attributes in the constructor like: `myNodeName(attrributeName: 'attributeValue')`
- You can pass a lambda to the new node and use it to populate its internal structure.

Comment: Since asking this question I've slowly worked out how the configure block works, but this answer gives me a much better idea of how it comes together - so thanks a lot for this.

Answer (score -1):

I have Jenkins version 1.6 (with copy artifact plugin) and you can do it in DSL like this:

```
job('my-job'){
  steps{
        copyArtifacts('job-id') {
            includePatterns('artifact-name')
            buildSelector { latestSuccessful(true) }
        }
    }
}
```

full example:

```
job('03-create-hive-table'){
    steps{
        copyArtifacts('seed-job-stash') {
            includePatterns('jenkins-jobs/scripts/landing/hive/landing-table.sql')
            buildSelector { latestSuccessful(true) }
        }
        copyArtifacts('02-prepare-landing-dir') {
            includePatterns('jenkins-jobs/scripts/landing/shell/02-prepare-landing-dir.properties')
            buildSelector { latestSuccessful(true) }
        }
        shell(readFileFromWorkspace('jenkins-jobs/scripts/landing/03-ps-create-hive-table.sh'))
    }
    wrappers {
        environmentVariables {
            env('QUEUE', 'default')
            env('DB_NAME', 'table_name')
            env('VERSION', '20161215')
        }
        credentialsBinding { file('KEYTAB', 'mycred') }
    }
    publishers{ archiveArtifacts('03-create-landing-hive-table.properties') }
}
```

Comment: Is this to add this as a parameter? Or to copy artifact as a step in the build?

Comment: I have it as a build step, for example my whole job def looks like this (edited in answer)

Comment: OK - looking at your example though, I can't see how this is creating a parameter for the build. It seems to be creating a Copy Artifact build step instead.

Comment: I came to this question with the exact same problem, and this answer does not address what OP asked. It is confusing, you are showing how to use copyArtifacts(), but we wanted to know how to properly provide a Build Parameter from one job to another one that uses copyArtifacts().